# Struts2 - É possível acessar um método do back end de uma Action no JSP?

Tags: java, java-ee, struts2, java-ee-6

Estou usando `Struts2` para construir uma aplicação web. Tenho um método numa classe chamada `BaseAction`, onde todas as outras Actions extendem-na, conforme está escrito abaixo:

```
public boolean isUserFullyLogged() {
    final Boolean isLogado = (Boolean) this.retrieveSessionAttribute(Constantes.LOGADO);
    return (isLogado != null) && isLogado.booleanValue();
}
```

Eu quero acessar este método no meu JSP para mostrar ou não determinado conteúdo e tentei as sintaxes abaixo para isto:

- `<s:if test="#userFullyLogged">Conteúdo</s:if>`
- `<s:if test="%{#userFullyLogged}">Conteúdo</s:if>`
- `<s:if test="userFullyLogged">Conteúdo</s:if>`
- `<s:if test="%{userFullyLogged}">Conteúdo</s:if>`

Mas nenhuma delas funcionou e o método simplesmente não é chamado. Alguém sabe onde estou errado e qual a sintaxe correta para chamar um método no back-end?

Comment: Por que simplesmente não verifica o atributo na sessão diretamente? Para evitar repetir o teste em todas as páginas (melhorando a manutenção), poderia criar uma tag personalizada cujo conteúdo só seja renderizado quando o usuário estiver logado e outra para quando não estiver logado. Um *tag file* seria bem prático.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está tentando acessar um atributo *userFullyLogged*, que não existe.

A sua chamada deveria ser simplesmente.

```
<s:if test="%{isUserFullyLogged()}">Conteúdo</s:if>
```

Você pode tentar melhor um pouco a performance fazendo com que o *isLogado* seja um atributo e não uma variavel, fazendo como exemplifico a seguir.

```
private Boolean isLogado;

public boolean isUserFullyLogged() {
    if (this.isLogado == null) {
        this.isLogado = (Boolean) this.retrieveSessionAttribute(Constantes.LOGADO);
    }
    return this.isLogado.booleanValue();
}
```

Deste modo você vai fazer uma única chamada ao metodo retrieveSessionAttribute e também um único cast e este valor será único para cada instancia de Action que extenda BaseAction.